# Duplicated subscription identifier error with RabbitMQ and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, stomp, spring-rabbit

I'm using STOMP over WebSocket (RabbitMQ 3.7.2 + Spring Boot 2.7.8) for server-client communications. I've recently found a lot of errors in logs:

```
2023-03-20 15:56:16,807 ERROR  [tcp-client-scheduler-1] org.springframework.core.log.CompositeLog: Received ERROR {message=[Duplicated subscription identifier], content-type=[text/plain], version=[1.0,1.1,1.2], content-length=[54]} session=<sid>, user=<uid> text/plain payload=A subscription identified by 'T_sub-3' already exists.
```

Does anyone know the reason of the issue? Possible fix?

Comment: This sounds like you already have a subscription/connection ongoing.  You need to look into your code and see at what point you are creating this.

You could also perhaps be reconnecting? And on reconnection, it might be trying to recreate an already open subscription

Comment: The problem is - I don't create the subscription manually on BE side. According to the log, it does tcp-client-scheduler and I can't understand why it tries to create the subscription with duplicated ID. But anyway, the initiator is UI client on JS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on UI side, where the subscription is initiated. The library that is used for WS IPC between BE and FE creates automatically subscription ID, that is unique for connection-topic. However, if someone manually subscribes with an ID that is already being used for another subscription, this can cause conflicts and errors (in my case it was an illegal JS script that was run in browser and was working like a bot).

**Example:**

1. Connect to ws
2. Subscribe to /topic/t0 with subId = sub-0
3. Subscribe to /topic/t1 with subId = sub-1
4. Subscribe to /topic/t2 with subId = sub-1 -- Duplicated subscription ID here.

**Flow:**

1. UI client inits subscription with duplicated ID
2. Backend receives it and sends subscription to RabbitMQ, using pool
3. RabbitMQ detects the duplication issue and responds with error
4. Backend logs the error